# Should the "this" keyword always be used when an object method calls another object method in java?

Tags: java, oop, this

```
public class Foo() {

  public Foo() {
    this.otherMethod();
    otherMethod();
  }

  public void otherMethod() {
    System.out.println("called");
  }

}

------
Main:

Foo foo = new Foo();
```

Both calls to `otherMethod` work as expected, and so I want to know **is there a special case where you have to use one over the other**.

It's hard to answer the question "when do I use `this`", but in this case, what would be the most logical option, and why?

Answer (score 3):

In the example you give, it makes no difference. `this` is used so that the compiler can tell the difference between members of different classes when they both have the same name and are in scope. For example,

```
public class Foo() {

     private int bar;

     public Foo(int bar) {
          this.bar = bar;
     }

}
```

if you were to omit the `this` in my example and simply wrote `bar = bar`, both occurrences of `bar` in that statement would be referring to the parameter variable because it has precedence over `this.bar` in that context.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no difference. A non-static method is always invoked on an object. When you do not specify one, the compiler calls it on `this`. Specifying `this` is entirely redundant.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, both method calls(`this`, and with out `this`) are the same. They both belong to the object that instantiated itself by using the constructor.

Generally, you always use object instance to call non-static methods. if there is no object instance, they implicitly belong to the object that own  the calling method(you can use `this`,or without `this`)